# Can't fetch data in cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

Hi i simulate data de to send in azureIoT. getting sample data works fine and when i use stream analytics with cosmos DB nothing is fetched in the data collection. everthing is empty.

i tried the change my connection (maybe my company's firewall) but nothing happens too

i would like to fetch data in cosmosDB by stream analytics because next step i want to use powerBI

ComsoDB sample works

[image]

[image]

and nothing in cosmoDB when i use stream analytics

Comment: Could you please check the error message from outputs section?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Cosmos DB settings for JSON output is mentioned correctly as follows:

[image]

Mandatory fields and description.

[image]

After defining Input, Output and query, click on the start job, then you can find the output in the Cosmos DB document.

[image]

Checkout the Azure Stream Analytics output to Azure Cosmos DB:

[image]

For more details, refer "[Azure Stream Analytics output to Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output)".

Hope this helps.